# Python script - tkinter and dash within function / external script (___main___)

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, program-entry-point, plotly-dash

I've started working on a project using tkinter to collect under a simple interface and menu few scripts I have written.
I’m sure there is a simple solution to the problem but I can’t figure out the way out.
One of the script I’ve used is based on an example available on the web that uses Dash to select and display statistics from a csv dataframe/pandas.

The dash scripts refreshes the web page when runs as main

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

and in the menu script tkinter:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the way I’ve understood searching through the web the menu tkinter relies on the loop in the script and the `__main__` statement of the script to work. Eventually I’ve discovered it was impossible to embed the dash script within the tkinter loop because the two `__main__` calls clash.

I’ve tried to run the dash script pointing from the main script to an external script but when I run it I found myself with 2 tkinter menu windows (I couldn’t expect less..) because both scripts call for main (?). I’m sure everything stands with my short understanding of the use of `__main__` and purpose of the main loops in scripts. Could someone point me in the right direction?
Many thanks

Comment: select code and use button `{}` to format code

Comment: { } noted, many thanks!

Comment: how do you run other scripts in `tkinter` ? Do you import and run function ?You can always import and run `app.run_server(debug=True)` in `tkinter` script. Problem can `mainloop` which have to run all time and `app.run_server(debug=True)` also has to run all time. It may have to use `threading`.

Comment: Hi, the other scripts are simple and limited to data crunching (pandas, numpy), they are functions within the main tkinter script loop. I guessed the issue is the 2 loops tkinter/dash running simultaneously. I had in mind to launch the external dash script -> kill the tkinter -> launch tkinter script again when dash one is done, but not sure it is a good solution. 'threading' I believe is beyond my capabilities.

Comment: you may need module [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to run `app.run_server(debug=True)` in tkinter script.